# Get textbox value in user control

Tags: vb.net

I'm anand. I have a problem about how to get text value in textbox in user control. I make a small application. I use Form1 as main form, and in the form I put one panel. In panel I will put custom user control that contain textbox. Now, I want to get the text on the textbox in user control and show it in the msgbox. Can anyone help me to fix this problem please?

Comment: You can set a property in the control that returns the textbox value. Then you only need to call that in your form. Ex: string text = _myControl.MyProperty;

Answer (score 2):

As André Leal said in the comments. If you define a public property in your user control you will be able to access the value.

```
Public Property textboxValue as String
     Get
          Return MyTextBox.text
     End Get
     Set(value as String)
          MyTextBox.text = value
     End Set
End Property
```

Then you can access it using code like this.

```
YourUserControl.textboxValue
```

If you don't need to edit the value of the textbox you can make the property readonly as follows.

```
Public ReadOnly Property textboxValue as String
     Get
          Return MyTextBox.text
     End Get
End Property
```